# Пропадаем модальное окно на сайте при низких разрешениях ( начиная с 991px )

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Есть список товаров, нажимаете на кнопку купить и по центру высвечивается окно, которое гласит, что товар добавлен в корзину и пару кнопок ( перейти в корзину или оформить заказ )
Но вот беда, окно пропадает из виду, когда переходишь на планшет или мобильное разрешение..

В чем может быть дело? Я даже не знаю, какой код толком, он не мой и я его не видел еще
Просто какие могут быть причины этого?

Comment: Причин может быть множество, последствия могут быть разные.

Comment: Какой ответ вы ожидаете? @SoulOFTrue ответил точно на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: Также прочитайте пожалуйста [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)